# AdMob Interstitial ads providing inconsistent DismissingOverlay callbacks

Tags: windows-phone-8, admob, dismiss, interstitial

I am trying to use AdMob Interstitial Ads in my application in Windows Phone 8.
The version of "GoogleAds.dll" I am using is: "6.5.13.0".
Everything is working fine as per the samples provided by AdMob.
I just had one query regarding the "DismissingOverLay" callback provided by the Interstitial Ad. It says that it is provided "After the interstitial/overlay is dismissed."
But in my case I am getting it in the following scenarios -
1.) When I dismiss the Ad by clicking the close image or hardware back key.(This is fine.)
2.) When the Ad is clicked and external browser is open and when the external browser is closed. (once when control leaves the app and once when it comes back.)
3.) When the hardware lock button is pressed. (in this case I get the dismissed callback but when I unlock the screen, I can still find the ad, not being dismissed.)

Why I just need a clarification on this because I am trying to run some custom code when the Ad is actually dismissed, but as I am getting these callbacks at various points I am unable to find out when to accept these callbacks and when to reject?